# spark is running a job with multiple partitions on single executor

Tags: apache-spark, partition, executor

I have a Spark 2.1.1 job that is running in a Mesos cluster. Spark UI is showing 32 active executors, and RDD.getNumPartitions is showing 28 partitions.
But only one (random) executor is doing any work, all others are marked as completed.
I added debug statements to executor code (stdout) and only one executor is showing those. Entire pipeline is structured as follows:
Get list of ids -> download JSON data for each id -> parse JSON data -> save to S3.

```
stage 1: val ids=session.sparkContext.textFile(path).repartition(28) -> RDD[String]

//ids.getNumPartitions shows 28
stage 2: val json=ids.mapPartitions { keys =>
  val urlBuilder ...
  val buffer ....
  keys map { key =>
    val url=urlBuilder.createUrl(id) //java.net.URL
    val json=url.openStream() ... //download text to buffer, close stream
    (id,json.toString)
  }
} -> RDD[Tuple2[String,String]]

stage 3: val output = json flatMap { t =>
  val values = ... //parse JSON, get values from JSON or empty sequence if not found
  values map { value => (t._1, value) }
} -> RDD[Tuple2[String,String]]

stage 4: output.saveAsTextFile("s3://...")
```

These are config settings for Spark binary:
--driver-memory 32g --conf spark.driver.cores=4 --executor-memory 4g --conf spark.cores.max=128 --conf spark.executor.cores=4

The stage that is running on one executor only is the second one.
I explicitly specified number of partitions (repartition(28)) in step one.
Has anyone seen such behavior before?
Thanks,

M

**SOLUTION**

I went the other way (see suggestion from Travis) and increased the number of partitions (after step 1) to 100. That worked, the job finished in a matter of minutes. But there is a side effect - now I have 100 partial files sitting in S3.

Comment: Can you provide a code and the command that you use to start your job?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your `.repartition()` stage is happening after you "Get list of ids".

It sounds like you are generating an empty set with 28 partitions first, and then getting the list of ids into a single partition.

**EDIT** after example code provided:

Is it possible that each task is completing quickly (i.e. within a few seconds)? I have seen spark not schedule tasks to idle executors when the tasks complete in a short amount of time, even with thousands of outstanding tasks. If that is the case, you may need fewer partitions to make each task take a little longer. Sometimes that is enough to trigger the task scheduler to schedule more tasks to idle executors.

Comment: I went the other way and increased the number of partitions (after step 1) to 100. That worked, the job finished in a matter of minutes. But there is a side effect - now I have 100 partial files sitting in S3.

Comment: @Travis Hegner , even i am having same problem ..my pipeline , read df from oracle with numOfPartitions = 20, insert into cassandra ....only one executor out of 20 been executed rest finishes in ms , What should I do to fix this , in the code ???

Comment: First, make sure this is not your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40938905/2639647. If that doesn't cover it, I'd post a new question with the code included.