# Spark JDBC read ends up in one partition only

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-jdbc

I have the below code snippet for reading data from a Postgresql table from where I am pulling all available data i.e. `select * from table_name` :

```
 jdbcDF = spark.read \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", self.var_dict['jdbc_url']) \
    .option("dbtable", "({0}) as subq".format(query)) \
    .option("user", self.var_dict['db_user']) \
    .option("password", self.var_dict['db_password']) \
    .option("driver", self.var_dict['db_driver']) \
    .option("numPartitions", 10) \
    .option("fetchsize", 10000) \
    .load()
```

Where var_dict is a dictionary containing my variables likes spark context , database creds etc.

Even when I am pulling millions of rows the result from below code returns 1 always:

```
partitions_num = jdbcDF.rdd.getNumPartitions()
```

Can someone advise if I am doing something wrong here? Ideally I would be expected to use maximum available resources rather then pulling the data to my master node only.

partitionColumn, lowerBound, upperBound cannot be used as my partition column is a timestamp and not numeric.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Partitioning in spark while reading from RDBMS via JDBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43150694/partitioning-in-spark-while-reading-from-rdbms-via-jdbc)

Comment: Please see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40938905/2639647

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From spark 2.4.0, date and timestamp column is also supported for partitioning,
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-22814